# Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create a sqoop workflow using Apache oozie, but when I execute the script I get below error :

```
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
```

When i checked the logs, it says the error is caused by :

```
Caused by:com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the propery file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml' (check CLASSPATH)
```

**Workflow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="sqoop-wf">
<start to="sqoop-node" />
<action name="sqoop-node">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>sqoop-site.xml</job-xml>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <command>import --libjars /usr/lib/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:mysql://mydatabase_Name.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/DB_NAME" --username NAGESHC --password nagesh@1234 --table TABLE_FIN --target-dir /user/hive/ooziesqoop -m 1 </command>
        <file>/usr/lib/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar</file>
   </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
 </action>
    <kill name="fail">
         <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
 <end name="success"/>
```

**Job.properties**

```
nameNode=hdfs://ip-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute.internal:8020
jobTracker=ip-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute.internal:8032
queueName=default
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://ip-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute.internal:8020/user/oozie/workflow.xml
outputDir=distcp
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/
```

I'm executing the script using below command :

```
oozie job -oozie http://ip-xxxxxxxxxxx.compute.internal:11000/oozie -config /home/job.properties -submit
```

Its related to CLASSPATH I guess ?

Answer (score 2):

have you checked your workflow.xml using validator tool? 
It would be helpful if you call in which Hadoop (cloudera or hortonwork) is being used.

```
$ oozie validate myApp/workflow.xml
```

mysql driver must be installed by default and you don't need to specify it. Or it can be made available in the sqoop/lib folder so sqoop will take it automatically Alternately, you can first check if your sqoop command is running correctly or not in cluster machine. If this runs, then it might be xml configuration issue.

```
sqoop import --libjars /usr/lib/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:mysql://Database_Hostname:xxxx/DB_name" --username xxxx --password nxxxx@xxxx --table table_Name --target-dir /user/hive/ooziesqoop -m 1
```